# How can I create animated ToggleButton?

Tags: android, animation, togglebutton

Yes, I can create ToggleButton with 2 pictures(On, Off) But I want to create a ToggleButton with 3-5 pictures.

For example, when is it OFF and I click:

1. Off picture
2. Middle picture
3. On picture

And when is it ON and I click:

1. On picture
2. Middle picture
3. OFF picture

So it is like frame animation, that I can use with duration with ImageView.

Comment: have you tried anything so far? for example, playing with STYLES ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

You can use [Frame Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame):
In `res/drawable/myanim.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pic_one" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pic_two" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pic_three" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

You can then use this animation as a plain drawable:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/myanim"/>
```

To start the animation you do

```
AnimationDrawable backgroundDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) image.getDrawable();
backgroundDrawable.start();
```

---

You can also use a [Value Animator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html). I haven't tested this, but you should be able to put something like this into onClick handler of you button:

```
int[] backgrounds = ...;//ids of the backgrounds for the button
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, backgrounds.length);
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        int i = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        int backgroundId = backgrounds[i];
        yourButton.setBackgroundResource(backgroundId);
    }
});
anim.setDuration(500); //0.5 seconds
anim.start();
```

Comment: Yes, but i think, that i can do it with ToggleButton style.

Comment: For example, I dont use picture for "on" or "off" background, i can use animation of other pictures.

Comment: @АлексейМаксимов OK, I have edited my answer, added an example of Frame Animation