# how to perform sliding animation of ON OFF Toggle button in android

Tags: android, animation, toggle

I want to perform sliding animation of On OFF button of toggle button.How I can do that.How to use animation in order to make slide between ON/OFF OFF/ON

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008555/how-can-i-create-animated-togglebutton) helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an animation-list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a14" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a15" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a16" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a17" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a18" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a19" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a20" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

where each of `a14` to `a20` is an image. Then you will need to create a selector drawable which defines how a button will look when it is in "on" state and how it will look when it is in "off" state. The drawable will point to the `animation-list`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/animatedbutton_on" />
<item android:state_checked="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/animatedbutton_off" />
</selector>
```

The selector then becomes the background of your toggle button.

Source: [animated toggle button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990603/animated-toggle-button)

Comment: Please explain that how I will be able to use animation-list xml in my Activity....How I am going to use variables of Animation...Please write the complete code.